Issue with certificate based windows login using c++ in credential provider
I am trying to acheive certificate based login in windows using credential provider code. This credential provider works perfectly for username password login flow. but failing for certificate based windows login. I have referred text. As mentioned in shared link, I have implemented ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization that
must return the serialized form of one of the following structs KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON. To read data from certificate I am using below code
BOOL ConstructAuthCertInfo(const KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON& rkiulIn, LPBYTE* ppbAuthInfo, ULONG* pulAuthInfoLen)
{
    UNICODE_STRING DomainName;
    UNICODE_STRING UserName;
    UNICODE_STRING Password;
    NTSTATUS Status;
    ULONG_PTR Ptr;
    ULONG AuthInfoLength;
    wstring WProvName;
    DWORD ProvSize = 0;
    wstring containerName;
    DWORD contSize = 0;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    DWORD dwKeySpec;

    // Fetching the certificate context from the certificate store  
    // and recieving the CSP handle for the user certificate
    HCERTSTORE      hStoreHandle = NULL;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT  pCertContext = NULL;
    LPCTSTR pszStoreName = _T("MY");
    //   LPCTSTR pszStoreName = _T("CA");

    CERT_CREDENTIAL_INFO certInfo;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    BOOL bStatus;
    DWORD dwHashLen = CERT_HASH_LENGTH;
    LPWSTR szMarshaledCred = NULL;
    HANDLE hToken;

    hStoreHandle = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, pszStoreName);

    if (hStoreHandle)
    {
        // Since my certificate store has only one user certificate, tring to retrieve PCERT_CONTEXT for it
        pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(
            hStoreHandle,
            PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING,
            0,
            CERT_FIND_ANY,
            NULL,
            NULL);

        if (pCertContext)
        {

            BOOL bFreeHandle;

            // acquire private key container to this certificate    
            if (CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(pCertContext, CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ALLOW_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, NULL, &hProv, &dwKeySpec, &bFreeHandle))
            {


                //Fetching the container name where the certificate is stored
                if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_CONTAINER, NULL, &contSize, 0))
                {
                    BYTE* contName = (BYTE*)malloc(contSize);
                    if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_CONTAINER, contName, &contSize, 0))
                    {
                        containerName = wstring(contName, contName + contSize);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return FALSE;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return FALSE;

                }

                //Fetching the CSP name where the certificate is stored
                if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_NAME, NULL, &ProvSize, 0))
                {
                    BYTE* ProvName = (BYTE*)malloc(ProvSize);
                    if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_NAME, ProvName, &ProvSize, 0))
                    {
                        WProvName = wstring(ProvName, ProvName + ProvSize);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hStoreHandle, pCertContext);

            // Get the subject name of each certificate.
            //std::vector<char> subjectName(256);
            //DWORD size = CertGetNameStringA(
            //    pCertContext,
            //    CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
            //    0,
            //    NULL,
            //    subjectName.data(),
            //    static_cast<DWORD>(subjectName.size())
            //);
            //wcout << "283" << endl;

            //if (size > 1) { // If CertGetNameStringA returns >1, it means it found a valid name
            //    std::wcout << "Certificate Subject: " << subjectName.data() << std::endl;
            //}
            //else
            //    std::wcout << "Not receied Certificate Subject: " ;

        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    DWORD dwReaderLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(L"") + 1;
    DWORD dwCardLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(L"") + 1;
    DWORD dwProviderLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(WProvName.c_str()) + 1;
    DWORD dwContainerLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(containerName.c_str()) + 1;
    DWORD dwBufferSize = dwReaderLen + dwCardLen + dwProviderLen + dwContainerLen;

    PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO CspInfo = (PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO)malloc(sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO) + dwBufferSize * sizeof(TCHAR));
    std::memset(CspInfo, 0, sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO));
    CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen = sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO) + dwBufferSize * sizeof(TCHAR);
    CspInfo->MessageType = 1;
    CspInfo->KeySpec = dwKeySpec;
    CspInfo->nCardNameOffset = ARRAYSIZE(CspInfo->bBuffer);
    CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset = CspInfo->nCardNameOffset + dwCardLen;
    CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset = CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset + dwReaderLen;
    CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset = CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset + dwContainerLen;
    std::memset(CspInfo->bBuffer, 0, sizeof(CspInfo->bBuffer));
    _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nCardNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nCardNameOffset, L"");
    _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset, L"");
    _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset, containerName.c_str());
    _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset, WProvName.c_str());



    const KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* pkilIn = &rkiulIn.Logon;

    // alloc space for struct plus extra for the three strings
    DWORD cb = sizeof(rkiulIn) +
        pkilIn->DomainName.Length +
        pkilIn->UserName.Length +
        pkilIn->Pin.Length +
        CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen;

    KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON* pkiulOut = (KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON*)CoTaskMemAlloc(cb);

    if (pkiulOut)
    {

        std::ZeroMemory(&pkiulOut->LogonId, sizeof(LUID));

        //
        // point pbBuffer at the beginning of the extra space
        //
        BYTE* pbBuffer = (BYTE*)pkiulOut + sizeof(*pkiulOut);

        //
        // set up the Logon structure within the KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON
        //
        KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* pkilOut = &pkiulOut->Logon;

        pkilOut->MessageType = pkilIn->MessageType;
        pkilOut->Flags = pkilIn->Flags;

        //
        // copy each string,
        // fix up appropriate buffer pointer to be offset,
        // advance buffer pointer over copied characters in extra space
        //
        _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->DomainName, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->DomainName);
        pkilOut->DomainName.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);
        pbBuffer += pkilOut->DomainName.Length;

        _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->UserName, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->UserName);
        pkilOut->UserName.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);
        pbBuffer += pkilOut->UserName.Length;

        _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->Pin, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->Pin);
        pkilOut->Pin.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);
        pbBuffer += pkilOut->Pin.Length;

        pkilOut->CspData = (PUCHAR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);
        pkilOut->CspDataLength = CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen;

        std::memcpy(pbBuffer, CspInfo, CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen);



        *ppbAuthInfo = (BYTE*)pkilOut;
        *pulAuthInfoLen = cb;

        return TRUE;
    }
}


Above code will read data from certificate and pass it to KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON& rkiulIn object. Above function will be called from GetSerialization function which will be called by logonui.exe
HRESULT GetSerialization(
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE* pcpgsr,
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION* pcpcs,
    PWSTR* ppwszOptionalStatusText,
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON* pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon
)
{
    
        //Certificate Based Auth
        KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON ckiul;
        KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* ckil = &ckiul.Logon;
        NTSTATUS nStatus;
        CHAR szProcName[] = "User32LogonProcess";
        CHAR szPackageName[] = NEGOSSP_NAME_A;

        LSA_STRING lsaProcName = { strlen(szProcName), strlen(szProcName) + 1, szProcName };
        LSA_STRING lsaPackageName = { strlen(szPackageName), strlen(szPackageName) + 1, szPackageName };
        LSA_STRING originName = {};
        char originNameStr[] = "CredentialProvider";
        originName.Buffer = originNameStr;
        originName.Length = (USHORT)0;
        originName.MaximumLength = 0;
        HANDLE lsaHandle;
        ULONG ulAuthPackage;
        LPBYTE pbAuthInfo = NULL;
        ULONG  ulAuthInfoLen = 0;
        LSA_OPERATIONAL_MODE dummy;
        LPVOID pProfileBuffer = NULL;
        ULONG ulProfileBufferLen = 0;
        LUID logonId;
        HANDLE hLogonToken;
        QUOTA_LIMITS quotas;
        NTSTATUS subStatus;
        HANDLE hToken = NULL;
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;



        int x;
        wchar_t doman[] = L"VDI.LOCAL";
        wchar_t usernme[] = L"test";
        wchar_t pn[] = L"";
        PWSTR domain = doman;
        PWSTR username = usernme;
        PWSTR pin = pn;
        ckil->MessageType = KerbCertificateLogon;
        ckil->Flags = 2;

        // Converting Domain Name to Unicode Format
        UnicodeStringInitWithString(domain, &ckil->DomainName);

        // Passing empty UserName as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/ns-ntsecapi-kerb_certificate_logon
        UnicodeStringInitWithString(username, &ckil->UserName);

        // Passing empty PIN since no PIN asked during enrollment
        UnicodeStringInitWithString(pin, &ckil->Pin);
        //End

        if (!ConstructAuthCertInfo(ckiul, &pbAuthInfo, &ulAuthInfoLen))


            ULONG scLogonSize = sizeof(ckiul.Logon);

            // Prepare the buffer for the credentials
            pcpcs->rgbSerialization = (BYTE*)CoTaskMemAlloc(scLogonSize);
            if (!pcpcs->rgbSerialization) {
                hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
            }
            else {
                CopyMemory(pcpcs->rgbSerialization, &ckiul.Logon, scLogonSize);
                pcpcs->cbSerialization = scLogonSize;

                pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider = CLSID_ACCOPS;  // Your provider's CLSID
                pcpcs->ulAuthenticationPackage = ulAuthPackage;
                *pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;
            }
        

        return hr;
    }

I tried above code snippets but I am getting The request is not supported as error from windows. I am stuck with this implementation, please let me know how can I achieve certificate based windows login using credential provider

AFAIK Certificate based authentication Use Digital signature deep inside as a basis of this process.
The main process of Winlogon is acts as System account so have no direct access to user certificates unless impersonate itself with the corresponding user.
The certificate located on Smartcard and its private key can be retrieved the way you use but the sequence of calls must be Smartcard -> Certificate -> Private key -> Signature.
One of important part is Smartcard's PIN to access private key. So it must be presented (unless your Smartcard is PIN-less).
The use of function CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey is the right way.

Thanks for your answer, but could you please elaborate more or it will be more helpful if you can share any code sample

Unfortunately my business requirements forced me no more use this function...
